# Can not copies files from a compressed folder to a non-compressed folder

Tags: copying, compression

I am having issues copying files and folders from a compressed .zip folder. What I used to do was open the zip folder and be able to select the files I would like, copy the files with Ctrl + C or even right click and select copy and then just paste them in the desired location/ folder.

Now when I do that, I do not get any error message, in fact I do not see anything, no pop up window or anything. But yet after I got back and try it again and go back into the destination folder I see a few of the files got copied, but not all of them.

If I unzip/extract the files and folder and I try and copy and paste them into the new location, it works without an issue. It has always worked before even without having to do the extra step.

I re-installed an older machine and put Windows 7 Pro on it, and I am accessing the files and folders from a network share. I do not think permissions NTFS/Share, are the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just click **Extract**.
Then select the destination of the files!

Comment: I can, but its not a solution. I would like to know how to get it back to be able to copy and then paste them into a new location.